# Order objects according to integer values

Tags: java, sorting

There is a class Entry with the private field `Num` and the class MyList that contains List of entries (Entry). I need to sort List of entries according to the values of Num. How to do this in the best way? Should I use `Collections.sort()`?

```
public class MyList()
{
  private List<Entry> entries;

  public MyList()
  {
    ...
  }

}

public class Entry()
{
  private int Num;
  private String Val;

  public MyClass()
  {
    this.Num = 0;
    this.Val = "";
  } 

  public void setNum(int Num)
  {
    this.Num = Num;
  }

  public int getNum()
  {
   return this.Num();
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you should either write a custom Comparator, or implement Comparable in `Entry`. Also your current code wouldn't compile for various reasons, and you should follow Java naming conventions for your fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the `Comparable` interface as follows (note I fixed a couple of mistakes and changed a couple var names to match conventions, per Jon Skeet's comment):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
private int num;
private String val;

public Entry() {
    this.num = 0;
    this.val = "";
} 

public void setNum(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public int getNum() {
    return this.num;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Entry entry) {
    if (this.num < entry.num) return -1;
    if (this.num > entry.num) return 1;
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("TEST 1");
    test1();

    System.out.println("\nTEST 2");
    test2();
}

public static void test1() {
    Entry e1 = new Entry();
    e1.setNum(5);

    Entry e2 = new Entry();
    e2.setNum(4);
    System.out.println("e1 = " + e1.getNum() + ", e2 = " + e2.getNum() + ", e1.compareTo(e2) = " + e1.compareTo(e2));

    Entry e3 = new Entry();
    e3.setNum(5);
    System.out.println("e1 = " + e1.getNum() + ", e3 = " + e3.getNum() + ", e1.compareTo(e3): " + e1.compareTo(e3));

    Entry e4 = new Entry();
    e4.setNum(6);
    System.out.println("e1 = " + e1.getNum() + ", e4 = " + e4.getNum() + ", e1.compareTo(e4): " + e1.compareTo(e4));
}

public static void test2() {
    List<Entry> list = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    int[] nums = { 5, 3, 9, 25, 1, -8 };
    for (int i : nums) {
        Entry e = new Entry();
        e.setNum(i);
        list.add(e);
    }
    Collections.sort(list);

    System.out.print("Orig list: ");
    for (int i : nums) {
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
    }

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Sorted list: ");
    for (Entry e : list) {
        System.out.print(e.getNum() + ", ");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a class implementing [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface and overriding the [compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) method. Then you can call the [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method with your collection and comparator class as the inputs

Here is a simple tutorial to help you with samples:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<YourObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2) {
        int cmp = Integer.compare(o1.getNum(), o2.getNum());
        return comp;
    }
}
```

You can use compare as well.

> int cmp = Integer.compare(a, b);// in Java 7
>
> int cmp = Double.compare(a, b); // before Java 7

Answer (score 1):

Use [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Make your `Entry` class implement this interface by providing the implementation for `compareTo()` which should return a `0` if this `Entry` object equals the other, a positive value if bigger or a negative one if small in comparison.

```
public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> // Use Generics
{
  private int Num;
  private String Val;

  public MyClass()
  {
    this.Num = 0;
    this.Val = "";
  }

  // getters/seters()

  public int compareTo(Entry otherEntry)
  {
   int num2 = otherEntry.getNum();
   return num == num2 ? 0 :
          (num > num2 ? 1 : -1);
  }

}
```

Then use `Collections.sort()` on a collection of `Entry` objects.

```
List<Entry> lisOfEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
// populate the list; then sort using
Collections.sort(listOfEntries);
```

To support multiple sort orders using different criteria, use [Comparator#compare()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) instead.