# How do I sort this list on the basis of one attribute?

Tags: java, sorting

There is a `linked list` that contains objects.The attributes of an object `o` are defined as :

```
bandWidth
ImageSize
VmCount
```

How do I sort the list on the basis of `bandWidth` ? Let the list be defined as :

```
list.add(o_1);
list.add(o_2);
list.add(o_3);
list.add(o_4);
```

Now I want to sort the list such that object with maximum bandwidth comes first in the list.

Comment: See *Comparator* interface for custom sorting.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675045/order-objects-according-to-integer-values/17675689#17675689

Answer (score 4):

Java's `Collections` class has a static `sort` method that takes in a `List` and a `Comparator` implementation

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {...}
```

Implement your own `Comparator` to return a value based on the `bandWidth`. Follow the rules of the `compare(T o1, T o2)` method

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer,
>   zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
>   to, or greater than the second.

Example

```
public static class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return o1.getField() - o2.getField();
    }       
}

public static class MyObject {
    private int field;
    public int getField() {
        return field;
    }
    public void setField(int field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain with a small example

Comment: @saplingPro Something like above. If `o1`'s field is bigger than `o2`'s, the method will return a positive number, signifying that `o1` should come after `o2` since `sort` orders in ascending order.

Comment: @saplingPro That is simply an implementation detail. If field on `o1` is bigger, then the difference will return a positive number. If it is equal, it will return 0. If it is smaller, it will return a negative number. As long as you follow the rules of what should be returned, you're fine. You could have done the same behavior with `if-else` and `>`, `<`, or `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimum working example:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

class MyClass {
    int bandWidth;
    int imageSize;
    int VmCount;

    public MyClass(int bandWidth, int imageSize, int VmCount) {
        this.bandWidth = bandWidth;
        this.imageSize = imageSize;
        this.VmCount = VmCount;
    }  
}

class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
    public int compare(MyClass object1, MyClass object2){
        return object2.bandWidth - object1.bandWidth; // sort the list in descending order
        //return object1.bandWidth - object2.bandWidth; // sort the list in ascending order
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyClass> objects = new LinkedList<>();
        objects.add(new MyClass(1,2,3));
        objects.add(new MyClass(3,2,3));
        objects.add(new MyClass(2,2,3));
        Collections.sort(objects, new MyComparator());
        for (MyClass object: objects) {
            System.out.println(object.bandWidth);
        }
    }
}
```

Since you don't fully understand this line of code:

```
return object2.bandWidth - object1.bandWidth;
```

Let's try implementing it in another way:

```
if (object2.bandWidth > object1.bandWidth) {
  return 1; //it can be any positive number
} else if (object2.bandWidth == object1.bandWidth){
  return 0;
} else {
  return -1; //it can be any negative number
}
```

Comment: can you please explain your compare method

Comment: @saplingPro See [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/).

Comment: what happens when I call `Collections.sort(objects, new MyComparator());` Though the result is fine, I do not understand how does the sorting take place ?

Comment: @saplingPro The `Collections.sort()` method has an implementation that uses your `Comparator` to sort the list. Go look at the source code of `TimSort.sort(..)` if you are interested.

Comment: I still haven't understood it. What is `compare` method meant for ? What does it do ?

Comment: @saplingPro Read its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). If that doesn't explain it, go find the Java source code for `Collections.sort()`. It is the interface method where you implement  your logic and that `sort()` uses to sort your list.